# How to use a single recurrent layer to predict 19000 steps into the future

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow

I want to use tensorflow to create A GAN, where the discriminator is a convolutional neural network and the generator is an lstm. The data I'm working with is about 19,000 time steps long. I want to make my generator make a 19,000 long sequence without creating 19,000 layers.

I tried to do this using a single LSTM cell, and then calling the cell 19,000 times:

```
def generator(z, num_neurons, reuse = None):
    with tf.variable_scope('gen',reuse=reuse):
        cell = tf.contrib.rnn.OutputProjectionWrapper(
        tf.contrib.rnn.BasicLSTMCell(num_units=num_neurons, 
activation=tf.nn.relu6),
        output_size=num_notes)
        outputs, states = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(cell, z[:,:,0:], 
dtype=tf.float32)
        lastoutput = outputs[:,:,-1]
        reshapedlastout = tf.reshape(lastoutput,[-1, num_notes,1])
        reshapedlastout = reshapedlastout/6
        z = tf.concat([z,reshapedlastout],2)
        for i in range(length-1):
            outputs, states = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(cell, z[:,:,-noisesize:], dtype=tf.float32)
            lastoutput = outputs[:,:,-1]
            reshapedlastout = tf.reshape(lastoutput,[-1,num_notes , 1])
            reshapedlastout = reshapedlastout/6
            z = tf.concat([z,reshapedlastout],2)
        z = z[:,:,-length:]
        return tf.reshape(z,[-1,num_notes,length, 1])
```

where length = 19000

I'm not sure if this creates 19000 different sets of weights(or something akin to that), which I think would be almost impossible to run. Secondly, I'm not sure if/how I need to pass the states from one use of the cell to the next. As I understand it, the states are what make RNNs good for sequence prediction, since every result is a function of the previous. However, I'm not really familiar with LSTMs, so I don't know if this has to be implemented in my code in some way or by reusing the same cell the states are automatically passed on. The reason I ask these questions is because my computer is taking a ton of time when trying to call this function and create the generator. However, my computer is generally very slow, so it could just be that.